# Window is closing immediately after I run program in PyQt 4 (anaconda) [PyCharm 4.5]

Tags: python, window, pyqt4, pycharm

So, I am trying to run a very simple program (a window) in Pycharm that is running anaconda 2.7 & PyQt4. Whenever I click the `Run` button it opens my program but closes the window too fast for me to even see it. May anyone, please help? Thank you!

P.S.

I'm very new to programming.

```
{__author__ = 'Jay'

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtGui.QWidget()

window.show()}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to block the execution of the program after you call `window.show()` so that the `window` object remains active otherwise it will be garbage collected. `app.exec_()` does this for you.

```
{__author__ = 'Jay'

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtGui.QWidget()

window.show()
app.exec_()}     # added this line
```